# Get sum of active record association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 tables `Campaigns` , `Contributions` , `Payments` . Campaign table holds information about campaign. Contribution holds info about contribution and Payments table hold info regarding payment that was successful processed thru payment gateway.

A campaign has many contributions.

A contribution has one payment.

[image]

So my problem is how can I get sum(:amount) of successful payments for a particular campaign?

This is how i am doing it right now but it has many performance issues

```
 @campaign = Campaign.find_by_uri(params[:permalink]).decorate
    @payment = @campaign.contributions.select {|cs| cs.payment.state == 'success' unless cs.payment.nil?}
    @total_contributions = 0
    @payment.each { |p| @total_contributions += p.amount }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a [has_many :through](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association for `payments` in `Campaign` model and get the sum of amount of successful payments as below:

**Campaign Model**

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contributions
  has_many :payments, through: :contributions
end
```

Then, you can filter the successful payments with the new association as below:

```
@campaign.payments.where(state: 'success')
```

Now, you can get sum of amount of each successful payment

```
@campaign.payments.where(state: 'success').sum(:amount)
```

So, the final code will become as below:

```
@campaign = Campaign.find_by_uri(params[:permalink]).decorate
@total_contributions = @campaign.payments.where(state: 'success').sum(:amount)
```

Comment: i find it so confusing to work with has_many through assoicaiton . Thanks @Gokul